# Google Maps Geocoding not working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to geocode the following address --> Noguera 429 San Antonio de Padua with Google Maps API. The address comes from a database and it's stored in the variable address. This is my code:

```
var address = '<?php echo $cerrajero["direccion"]?>'+' '+'<?php echo $cerrajero["ciudad"]?>';
var myCenter;

function initialize(){

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode({
        "address": address
    },function(results){
         myCenter = results[0].geometry.location;
    });

    var mapProp = {
        center:myCenter,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position:myCenter,
        icon:'css/images/pin.png'
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

and then:

```
<div id="googleMap" class="map" style="height:250px;"></div>
```

and finally:

```
.map{
    margin: 0 0 18px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

But my map isn't showing up. It just shows a grey block, is anything wrong with the javascript?

PS: The variable address is ok, I checked it with the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geocoder is asynchronous, you have to use the results in the callback function when/where they are available.

**code snippet:**

```js
var address = 'Noguera 429 San Antonio de Padua';
var myCenter;

function initialize() {

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  geocoder.geocode({
    "address": address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      myCenter = results[0].geometry.location;
      var mapProp = {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter,
        // icon:'css/images/pin.png'
      });

      marker.setMap(map);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```